# How to sort range chronologically vba

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, datetime

I am trying to sort the given range in the chronological order rather than in Ascending order by their values in column A

Below code checks if any value is changed in columns from B to Z and puts date and time in respective cell row in col A.

> Aim of this macro is to put the last edited row at the bottom of the table.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim m As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim keyRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Range("A2:Z1048567")
    Set keyRange = Range("A2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       For Each Cel In Target
        If Not Intersect(Target, Cel) Is Nothing And Cel.Column > 1 And Cel.Column <= 26 Then
            m = Cel.Row
            With ActiveSheet.Range("A" & m)
                .Value = Date & " " & Time
                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM "
            End With
            DataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
       Next Cel

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I may have completely missed the point of the question but in any event (npi), ALWAYS use `Application.EnableEvents = False` before altering any data in a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. Without it you run the risk of triggering another event and the procedure will run on top of itself, possibly triggering another event and a cascading failure. Remember to use `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have forces a left cell alignment, the datetimes in column A are actually 'text-that-looks-like-a-datetime'. On top of that, they are in a DMY configuration and VBA is very EN-US-centric (i.e. MDY) regardless of what the computer's regional system settings are set for dates.

You can use a conversion routine like **CDate** but the results are unreliable. In cases of unambiguous dates like `18/01/2016 10:08:52 AM`, the conversion will be correct. However, if you have an ambiguous datetime like `06/01/2016 10:08:52 AM` the CDate conversion will most likely return `01-Jun-2016 10:08:52` instead of the 'correct' `06-Jan-2016 10:08:52`. The times need to be split to an unused column and then combined back into the repaired dates.

Use the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) command and force the correct DMY date conversion with the [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Run this routine on your existing data by first selecting all of the dates. Do NOT include your column header label as this is longer than the first split point of the dates. Selecting A2 first then tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>▼</kbd> should do nicely.

```
Sub repair_Dates_by_Selection()
    Dim dt As Range
    With Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)
        .Columns(1).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 4), Array(10, 1))
        For Each dt In .Cells
            dt = dt.Value2 + dt.Offset(0, 1).Value2
        Next dt
        .Columns(1).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Delete
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

Once this has completed, the datetimes in column A should be real dates with real times formatted in a DMY configuration.

**[Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:Z")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In Intersect(Target, Columns("B:Z"))
            With cel
                Debug.Print "!" & cel.Address
                If .Row > 1 Then
                    Intersect(Columns(1), cel.EntireRow).Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM_);@"
                End If
            End With
        Next cel
        With Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above adds event disabling/enabling to your original code. The [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) is used to determine the applicable cells. The `Now` is used to create true datetimes for the timestamp as opposed to text-that-looks-a-datetime. The former can be easily sorted chronologically, the latter is unreliable at best.